# Efficient way to loop through variables with number patterns in Python and append to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

so my variables are these:

> answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, ..., answer20

and I want to append all of them to a list in order.
is there a neat way to do this?

I can just use extend and write all of them one by one but that's inefficient

I've tried writing the variables manually but there is more that 20 variables that I'm working with

```
result_list = []
result_list.extend(answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, ...)
```

Comment: `result_list = [globals()[f"answer{x}"] for x in range(1,21)]` ...but that just stores the values. It sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/209820). Why not just use a list instead of all those variables to begin with?

Comment: thank you @001, will try to ask my questions better next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I guess you can just do this:

```
result_list = []
result_list.extend([globals()[f'answer{i}'] for i in range(1,21)])
```

This will get the values from the global scope, you can also use `globals().get(f'answer{i}')`

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are not global (e.g. if you're doing this inside a function), you can use locals() instead of globals():

Here's a different way to write the same thing as D4Vinci's answer, but using locals instead:

```
*result_list, = map(locals().get,map("answer{}".format,range(1,21)))
```